# Prove or disprove that $[L:K] = \deg(p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension and let $\beta \in L$. If $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ then is it true that $[L:K] = \deg(p)$? If not, give a counterexample.

Can someone help me figure out if this is true or not?

Comment: What if $\beta\in K$?

Comment: My problem says only this @Bernard

Comment: You write "the minimal polynomial" but I think you have to specify it as "the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $K$."

Comment: @Arthur Have you looked at the other one? It is identical.

Comment: @uniquesolution I only looked at the title first, and misread it to boot. Then I actually looked at the question, and that's why I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @uniquesolution so it is false then?

Comment: @mandella - Why don't you have a look at it.

Comment: @uniquesolution I was reading it, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @mandella the primitive-element theorem might be of interest to You (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$ and consider the extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Consider the minimal polynomial of $i$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is $p(x)=x^{2}+1$, i.e. $\deg(p)=2$. But $$[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4\neq 2=\deg(p).$$

Comment: Isn 't $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ and $\{1,i,\sqrt{2}\}$ a basis for the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $K$?

Comment: If it is $3$ then "not equal still holds? @PeterMelech

Comment: Yes sure the argument is fine!

Comment: @PeterMelech $[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ cannot be equal to 3 since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ is a subfield of $K$, which has degree 2 (so 2 must divide the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$). So a basis is $\lbrace 1, i, \sqrt{2}, i\sqrt{2}\rbrace$.

Comment: @YumekuiMath Ah sure! Thanks a lot!